# What does Śāripūtrābhidharma Satipatthana sources mention about food? Does other Theravada source have such references?

Tags: vipassana, reference-request, history, satipatthana

According to [Satipatthana Mula (By Sujato Bhikkhu edited by Piya Tan)](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/13.4-Satipatthana-Mula-m10-sujato.pdf) Śāripūtrābhidharma versions of the Satipatthana contains a reference to food. What exactly does it say about food and does Theravada sources have similar references else where? Is food referenced as one of the [elements (Mahābhūta)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mah%C4%81bh%C5%ABta)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it cautioned the practitioner not to crave and endulge the 6 sense objects (form, sound, smell, etc.), clothing, food, drink, medicine, etc. for craving of those leads to suffering.
The Pali source mentioned the Four Nutriments which includes food as the physical nutriment, contact, mental volition, and consciousness. Analysis and various suttas are available [here](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nyanaponika/wheel105.html)